# 'type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' ' is the error I receive

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to upload form data to Cloud Firestore. I've tried different combinations of maps and hashmaps but can't get it to work. The same program is able to read data from the store seamlessly but can't write. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
MaterialButton(child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                            Text('Add item'),
                          ]),
                      onPressed: () => {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                            HashMap<dynamic, dynamic> listItem =
                                new HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>();
                            listItem["Description"] = _itemName;
                            listItem["Due"] = _due;
                            listItem["ID"] = _id;
                            listItem["Priority"] = _prioritySwitch;
                            listItem["Progress"] = _progress;
                            listItem["Reminder"] = _reminderSwitch;
                            listItem["SliderSwitch"] = _sliderSwitch;
                            listItem["Start"] = _start;

                            Firestore.instance
                                .collection("Task Lists")
                                .add(listItem.);
                          }
                          ;
                        }),
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Have you tried using Map<String,Dynamic>  listItem =
                                new Map<String, dynamic>();

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of your HashMap to Map:

```
MaterialButton(child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                            Text('Add item'),
                          ]),
                      onPressed: () => {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                            Map<String, dynamic> listItem =
                                new Map<String, dynamic>();
                            listItem["Description"] = _itemName;
                            listItem["Due"] = _due;
                            listItem["ID"] = _id;
                            listItem["Priority"] = _prioritySwitch;
                            listItem["Progress"] = _progress;
                            listItem["Reminder"] = _reminderSwitch;
                            listItem["SliderSwitch"] = _sliderSwitch;
                            listItem["Start"] = _start;

                            Firestore.instance
                                .collection("Task Lists")
                                .add(listItem.);
                          }
                          ;
                        }),
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JSON format instead and you save the explicit creation of Map:

```
  Firestore.instance.collection("Task Lists").add(<String, dynamic>
  {
    "Description" : _itemName,
    "Due" : _due,
    "ID" : _id,
    "Priority" : _prioritySwitch,
    "Progress" : _progress,
    "Reminder" : _reminderSwitch,
    "SliderSwitch" : _sliderSwitch,
    "Start" : _start,
  });
```